# Why regular operations are not based on their in-place corresponding operation?

Tags: python, operator-overloading, in-place

To me, the only difference is that the regular operation needs one more instantiation, and the result is held by this new instance. And thus the regular implementation should call the other.

[But](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types) : *these (in-place) methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, self). If a specific method is not defined, or if that method returns NotImplemented, the augmented assignment falls back to the normal methods.*

Here, i understand that the standard way is the opposite of mine : `__iadd__` relies on `__add__` **EDIT** in the sense that `__add__` will be called in last resort.

So why `__add__` is the default way to achieve the addition and not `__iadd__`, whereas it should require less processing ?
**END EDITING**

A bit of context : the question came while implementing a Polynomial class, for learning purpose. I have written:

```py
class A:
    ...
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        "processing resulting in modification of attributes of self"
        return self
    def __add__(self, other):
        res = self.copy() # A.copy() being implemented as well
        res += other
        return res
```

Comment: `__iadd__`, I think, would rarely rely on `__add__`, because it wouldn't need whatever new instance `__add__` creates.

Comment: Sorry, i've been unclear here, by rely on, i mean `__iadd__` will call `__add__` in last resort. Thus, the default algorithm is the one held by `__add__`.

Comment: *"`__iadd__` will call `__add__` in last resort"* - Says who?

Comment: _If `__iadd__()` does not exist, or if `x.__iadd__(y)` returns `NotImplemented`, `x.__add__(y)` and `y.__radd__(x)` are considered, as with the evaluation of `x + y`._ from the python's documentation.

Comment: Yeah. Exactly. **If __iadd__() does not exist, or if x.__iadd__(y) returns NotImplemented.** In which case it **doesn't** call `__add__`. How could something that doesn't exist call anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inplace operations likely modify their operands. In the example you give, you use `A.copy()` to avoid that.

Some types do not allow modifications (tuples, for example, are immutable). Thus they don't allow inplace operations.

Also, inplace operations are not exactly intuitive to someone new to programming, or even to someone new to python. It's a nice feature of the language, but that's all.

Overall, regular operations are the 'normal' form of operations. If you're writing a new class and want to support operators, you'll probably think of the regular operators first, and the inplace ones later, or not at all. With your way, inplace would not work if only regular was defined.

But sometimes performance is indeed an issue, and inplace would allow for a more efficient implementation. That's why you have the possibility to define the inplace operation rather then just have it call the regular one.

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood the documentation and confused the operators and the methods. It's not `__iadd__` that calls `__add__`, it's the `+=` operator (or rather the part of the interpreter that handles it) that calls it. That operator first tries to call `__iadd__`, and if that doesn't work (because `__iadd__` doesn't exist or returns `NotImplemented`), then the operator tries `__add__`. That's what the documentation means.

It also wouldn't make sense for `__iadd__` to call `__add__` because that would create a new object which isn't needed.

When a type **does** implement `__iadd__`, then likely also `__add__`, and quite possibly `__add__` does call `__iadd__` after making a copy, just like you did. Or neither calls the other, and both call some "update" method, as [for example](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/17a82a1d16a46b6c008240bcc698619419ce5554/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L320-L329) `OrderedDict.__ior__` and `OrderedDict.__or__` do:

```
    def __ior__(self, other):
        self.update(other)
        return self

    def __or__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, dict):
            return NotImplemented
        new = self.__class__(self)
        new.update(other)
        return new
```